# Find runtime location of a letter in the text of a multi-line UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

Say I had a multi-line (can be any number of lines) `UIButton` positioned in any space in a `UIViewController`, where the width of the `UIButton` is constrained by the width of of the whole `UIViewController's view`, its text is centered inside of the UIButton and word wrapping is on, like so:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI170.png)

If I want to find the runtime location of the * in the picture in terms of the whole `UIViewController's space`, how would I do so?

I attempted to use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475593/swift-how-do-i-find-the-positionx-y-of-a-letter-in-a-uilabel) but it only works for single line text and so I can't seem to figure how I am supposed to make it work for multi-line (aka I dont know on which line the * is) text, centered and word wrapped.

Comment: Do you have to use a `UIButton`? Or is using a `UITextView` with a `UITapGesture` (to perform actions) an option?

Comment: Yeah I could, but how would that help with finding the position of a character in the text?

Comment: Since I can't provide an answer, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11487125/4539192) answer, it ought to give you a rough idea of what I mean.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will see if I can get that to work

Answer (score 0):

To do this use a UITextView and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468187/find-cgpoint-location-of-substring-in-textview) post. Just follow the answer and it should work fine.